# Python looping to other functions using one function.

Tags: python, loops

I'm making an RPG game that refers to fightmode() for every battle.
So for my first scenerio, I made it "def game1()" and then from there, it leads to fightmode(). Once the battle in fightmode() is finished, I would like it to go to game2() or game3() etc etc. Is there a way for me to do this? This is my code so far.

I do not have game2() coded out yet though, but I hope what I said was understandable.

```
import time
import random
global myhp
myhp = 20
mydmg = random.randint(2,5)
global mgold
mgold = 0

def start():
    print "Hello there.";   time.sleep(.5)
    myname = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    print "Welcome %s, this is..." %myname; time.sleep(.5)
    uname = myname.upper()
    print "\t\t\tTHE ADVENTURES OF %s" %uname;  time.sleep(.5)
    choice0 = ''
    allowed = ["y", "n"]
    while choice0.lower() not in allowed:
        choice0 = raw_input("\nWould you like to play the game? Y/N "); time.sleep(.5)
        choice0 = choice0.lower()
    if choice0 == "y":
        game1()
    if choice0 == "n":
        print "Alright, bye!"

def fightmode(name, hp, dmg_min, dmg_max, gold):
    global myhp
    print '\n\n\nYou are in a fight with %s' %name; time.sleep(.5)
    print '%s has %sHP' %(name, hp);    time.sleep(.5)
    while myhp > 0 and hp > 0:
        print '\n\t1. Attack \n\t2. Guard \n\t3. Run away.';    time.sleep(.2)
        opt1= ''
        allowed = ["1", "2", "3"]   
        while opt1 not in allowed:
            mydmg = random.randint(2,5)
            dmg = random.randint(dmg_min, dmg_max)
            opt1 = raw_input("\nWhat will you do? ")
            if opt1 == "1":
                hp = hp - mydmg 
                myhp = myhp - dmg
                print "\nYou have inflicted %d damage on %s. %s's HP is %s" %(mydmg, name, name, hp);   time.sleep(.5)
                if hp >= 1:
                    print "%s attacked you and did %d damage. Your HP fell down to %s" %(name, dmg, myhp);  time.sleep(.5)
                    if myhp <= 0 :
                        print"\n\tYou have been defeated...";   time.sleep(.5)
                        restart = ''
                        allowed =["y", "n"]
                        restart = restart.lower()
                        restart = raw_input("\n\tWould you like to start over? ");  time.sleep(.5)
                        if restart == "y":
                            myhp = 20
                            game1()     
            if opt1 == "2":
                myhp = myhp + 5
                print "You are now guarding yourself. Your HP is now %d" %myhp; time.sleep(.5)
                myhp = myhp - dmg
                print "%s attacked you and did %d damage. Your HP fell down to %s" %(name, dmg, myhp);  time.sleep(.5)
            if opt1 == "3":
                chance = random.randint(0,11)
                if chance == 1:
                    print "You have sucessfully run away";  time.sleep(.5)
                else:
                    myhp = myhp - dmg
                    print "You failed to run away.";    time.sleep(.5)
                    print "%s attacked you and did %d damage. Your HP fell down to %s" %(name, dmg, myhp);  time.sleep(.5)
    if myhp <= 0 :
        print"\n\tYou have been defeated...";   time.sleep(.5)
        restart = ''
        allowed =["y", "n"]
        restart = restart.lower()
        restart = raw_input("\n\tWould you like to start over? ");  time.sleep(.5)
        if restart == "y":
            myhp = 20
            game1() 
    if hp <= 1 :
        global mgold
        print"You have defeated %s and earned %d gold." %(name, gold);  time.sleep(.5)
        mgold = mgold + gold
        print"You have %d gold." %mgold;    time.sleep(.5)


def fightmode0():
    print """\n\nThis is your first fight. You have 3 seconds each turn
if you fail to make a move in 3 seconds, you will lose your turn.

By "Attacking", you inflict damage on the enemy\'s HP, get it down to 0 to defeat him.
If your HP reaches 0, you will be defeated. 

By "Guarding", you will regain 10HP back, but that counts as your turn.
By defeating enemies, you gain gold Use gold to purchase upgrades 
when you come across a shop.

You can choose to "Run Away", but you will only have a 1/10 chance of it being sucessful
"""
    raw_input("\nPress any key to continue to battle"); time.sleep(.5)
    fightmode("Scrawny Thug", 15, 1, 5, 4)

def game1():
    print "\nYou wake up and find yourself locked in a room...";    time.sleep(.5)
    print "You think you're kidnapped.";    time.sleep(.5)
    print "Yea, you're probably kidnapped.";    time.sleep(.5)
    print "You hear footsteps approaching the door..."; time.sleep(.5)
    print "\n\t1. Remain in fetal position \n\t2. Attempt a sneak attack" ; time.sleep(.5)
    choice1 = ''
    allowed = ["1", "2"]
    while choice1 not in allowed:
        choice1 = raw_input("\nWhat will you do? ");    time.sleep(.5)
    print "\nThe doorknob rattles...";  time.sleep(.5)
    print "...";    time.sleep(.5)
    print "...";    time.sleep(.5)
    if choice1 == "1":
        print '"Hey!"'; time.sleep(.7)
        print '"Get up maggot!"';   time.sleep(.7)
        print 'You see that the thug is small and scrawny'; time.sleep(1)
        print 'He grabs you by your hair and pulls you up'; time.sleep(1)
        print "\n\t1. Punch him in the face. \n\t2. Do nothing" ;   time.sleep(1)
        choice1_1 = ''
        allowed = ["1", "2",]
        while choice1_1 not in allowed:
            choice1_1= raw_input("\nWhat will you do?? ");  time.sleep(.5)
        if choice1_1 == "1":
            print '\nYou punch the scrawny thug and he lets you go';    time.sleep(.5)
            print '"You\'re going to pay for that."';   time.sleep(.5)
            print '\n\t\t>>>>>>>>>>ENTERING FIGHT MODE';    time.sleep(.5)
            print '\n\t\t>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';    time.sleep(.5)
            print '\n\t\t>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';    time.sleep(.5)
            print '\n\t\t>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';    time.sleep(.5)
            print '\n\t\t>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>';    time.sleep(.5)
            fightmode0()



game1()
```

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom where you call `game1()`, add calls for `game2()`, etc.:

```
game1()
game2()
game3()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was overthinking it and didn't even see that